# how can I copy row values in columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this:

```
Service_order     Part_code1  Part_code2       Part_code3     Part_code4        Part_code5

    4182864919    GH82-11218A GH96-09406A      GH81-13594A    GH02-11552A       GH02-11553A
    4182868153    GH97-17670B             
    4182929636    GH97-17260C GH02-10203A         
    4182953067    GH97-17940C             
    4182954688    GH82-10555A GH97-17852A      GH81-13071A     
    4182955036    GH97-17940C
```

But I want to show it in a new table like this:

```
    Service_order     partCodes
    4182864919        GH82-11218A
    4182864919        GH96-09406A
    4182864919        GH96-09406A
    4182864919        GH02-11552A
    4182864919        GH02-11553A
    4182868153        GH97-17670B   
    4182929636        GH97-17260C
    4182929636        GH02-10203A 
.
.
.and so on...
```

I tried Join and Union but it didn't give me the result that I wanted.
what should I do for this problem?

Comment: This might be poor database schema.
Please read more about database normalization:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, an easy way to unpivot uses `APPLY`:

```
select t.service_order, v.part_code
from t cross apply
     (values(Part_code1), (Part_code2), (Part_code3), (Part_code4), (Part_code5)
     ) v(part_code)
where v.part_code is not null;
```

In either MySQL or SQL Server, you can use `union all`:

```
select t.service_order, part_code1 as part_code from t where part_code1 is not null union all
select t.service_order, part_code2 as part_code from t where part_code2 is not null union all
select t.service_order, part_code3 as part_code from t where part_code3 is not null union all
select t.service_order, part_code4 as part_code from t where part_code4 is not null union all
select t.service_order, part_code5 as part_code from t where part_code5 is not null;
```

Comment: If we select from two tables shouldn't we join the other table as well?

Comment: @erfan . . . Your question only mentions one table, quite explicitly.  If you have multiple tables, then you should ask another question.  If you don't understand `cross apply`, then a good place to start is the documentation:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: If you could see your own code"select t.service_order, v.part_code", there is a T table which you select the service order and V table that you select part code. I'm talking about those two.

Answer (score 1):

If a service order can have several partCodes, you should have a table with composite keys as part of normalisation.
In this case, service_order and partCodes would be the unique key for each row.

With such schema all you need is a `SELECT * FROM [table_name]`, assuming you have a SQL database.